# ASP.NET MVC 5 custom route goes to wrong action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm having trouble with a custom route which isn't being routed correctly. Both `@Html.ActionLink` and `@Html.RouteLink` create the correct url `fantasy/1/fantasyleague1/matchups` which when clicked never touches the Matchups Action and incorrectly routes to `fantasy/1/fantasyleague1/settings?round=3`

RouteDebugger shows:

> Matched Route: Fantasy/{leagueID}/{leagueSlug}/Settings
>
> Generated URL: /fantasy/11/fantasyleague1/matchups/3 using the route "Fantasy/{leagueID}/{leagueSlug}/Matchups/{round}"

RouteConfig.cs

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Fantasy League Matchups",
        url: "Fantasy/{leagueID}/{leagueSlug}/Matchups/{round}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Fantasy", action = "Matchups", leagueSlug = UrlParameter.Optional, round = UrlParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { leagueID = @"\d+" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Fantasy League Settings",
        url: "Fantasy/{leagueID}/{leagueSlug}/Settings",
        defaults: new { controller = "Fantasy", action = "Settings", leagueSlug = UrlParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { leagueID = @"\d+" }
    );
```

FantasyController.cs

```
    // GET: /Fantasy/{leagueID}/{leagueSlug}/Matchups/{round}
    public ActionResult Matchups(int leagueID, string leagueSlug = null, int round = -1) {
        var fantasyLeague = DataContext.FantasyLeagues.Where(l => l.ID == leagueID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (fantasyLeague != null) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(leagueSlug) || round == -1) {
                return RedirectToActionPermanent("Matchups", "Fantasy", new { leagueID = leagueID, leagueSlug = fantasyLeague.Slug, round = fantasyLeague.CurrentRound });
            }

            var userInLeague = User != null && User.Identity != null && fantasyLeague.FantasyTeams.Any(t => t.Owner.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
            var fantasyMatches = fantasyLeague.FantasyMatches.Where(fm => fm.Round == round).ToList();

            return View("Matchups", new FantasyMatchupsViewModel {
                FantasyLeague = fantasyLeague,
                FantasyMatches = fantasyMatches,
                Round = round,
                UserInLeague = userInLeague
            });
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // GET: /Fantasy/{leagueID}/{leagueSlug}/Settings
    public ActionResult Settings(int leagueID, string leagueSlug = null) {
        var fantasyLeague = DataContext.FantasyLeagues.Where(l => l.ID == leagueID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (fantasyLeague != null) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(leagueSlug)) {
                return RedirectToActionPermanent("Settings", "Fantasy", new { leagueID = leagueID, leagueSlug = fantasyLeague.Slug });
            }

            var userOwnsLeague = User != null && User.Identity != null && fantasyLeague.Commissioner.UserName == User.Identity.Name;

            return View("Settings", new FantasySettingsViewModel {
                FantasyLeague = fantasyLeague,
                UserOwnsLeague = userOwnsLeague,
                Name = fantasyLeague.Name,
                MaxPlayers = fantasyLeague.MaxPlayers,
                LockoutPeriod = fantasyLeague.LockoutPeriod,
                PasswordProtected = fantasyLeague.PasswordProtected,
                Password = fantasyLeague.Password
            });
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: I suspect this isn't a routing problem at all. You are using `RedirectToActionPermanent`, which produces a 301 redirect. Most browsers cache 301 redirects, so the behavior you are likely seeing is from the first hit that your browser cached. Most likely you should just change these to `RedirectToAction`, which produce a "normal" 302 redirect that is not cached. It seems odd that you are putting 301 redirects into a controller.

Comment: @NightOwl888 You're right, it was a cached 301 redirect. I was just following with what I've read elsewhere that using a 301 to add the slug would result in better seo, but I didn't fully understand the consequences.

Comment: 301 is for SEO purposes, but it is intended to *update* a URL that is already in the wild (that is, already indexed by search engines) to a new (permanent) location.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Could you please post this comment as an answer so I can accept it? It lead me on to clear my browser cache solving the routing/redirect problem, and convert `RedirectToActionPermanent` to `RedirectToAction` preventing it from catching me out again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this is not a routing problem at all. You are using `RedirectToActionPermanent`, which produces a 301 redirect. Most browsers cache 301 redirects, so the behavior you are seeing is likely from the first hit your browser cached.

Instead of using `RedirectToActionPermanent`, you should use `RedirectToAction`, which will generate a "normal" 302 redirect.

301 redirects are for ensuring URLs that have already been put into the wild (that is, users have potentially bookmarked and/or search engines have potentially indexed) are updated to the new location. They should generally not be used just to get a user from URL A to URL B within your application.